# vuejs : how to preload image inside a component

Tags: vue.js

I have images inside a component not displayed at launch.
When i show my component, my images are not displayed instantly, but are loaded.

I would like to preload my images on the root app, to be instantly displayed when the component is active.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

components are bind to dom only when they are created. images will be loaded only when dom sent request. you can try something

```
let image = new Image(); 
image.src = 'something.png'.
```

this will trigger a network request. you can use the image variable as props  to component

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with `css` background images. Simply add this css to your global styles:

```css
html {
  background-image: url('url1.jpg'),
    url('url2.jpg'),
    url('url3.jpg'); // list all images here
    background-size: 0;
}
```

This might be a little bit hacky, but all images get preloaded asynchronously. From here on you can optimize it by going more specific on where to apply the styles e.g. scoped in child components or wherever you want.

If you have a lot of images you could also write a simple webpack plugin which generates this code dynamically.

Comment: This will preload images even if they are not necessary during the DOM render, not a prefered way

Comment: definitely hacky, but just what i needed